# How to upgrade a Trezor device without wallet.trezor.io?

Tags: privacy, trezor

How to update a Trezor device without the Trezor backend?

The Trezor backend at wallet.trezor.io is suboptimal from a privacy perspective. Many people choose to use Electrum, Wasabi or any other wallet that offers more privacy.

The Trezor Android app may be able to upgrade a Trezor wallet this but it didn't do anything for me plus it's unclear whether it sends your XPUB to Trezor's servers anyway. So is it possible to update a Trezor hardware wallet without going to wallet.trezor.io or the Trezor Android app, and if so, how?

Comment: It may be possible to use the trezor command line client available here: https://github.com/trezor/trezor-firmware/tree/master/python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use the trezor command line client `trezorctl` available [here](https://github.com/trezor/trezor-firmware/tree/master/python) to install a firmware you downloaded from trezor as described in the developer docs [here](https://docs.trezor.io/trezor-firmware/legacy/index.html).

***BE SURE YOU HAVE A BACKUP OF YOUR SEED***

"1) Pick version of firmware binary listed on https://wallet.trezor.io/data/firmware/1/releases.json
2) Download it: `wget -O trezor.signed.bin https://wallet.trezor.io/data/firmware/1/trezor-1.6.1.bin`
3) Use trezorctl dry-run mode to get the firmware fingerprint:

```
trezorctl firmware-update -n -f trezor.signed.bin
```

Step 3 should produce the same fingerprint like your local build (for the same version tag)."

Then it can be installed from the command line:

WARNING: This will erase the recovery seed stored on the device! You should never do this on Trezor that contains coins!

Build with MEMORY_PROTECT=0 or you will get a hard fault on your device.

Switch your device to bootloader mode, then execute:

```
trezorctl firmware-update -f path/to/firmware.bin
```